# How can I sync my maven artifacts to jcenter?

Tags: maven, deployment, synchronization, bintray, jcenter

I have deploy my fist version to the maven central repository. Now I want sync this to JCenter / Bintray. Is this possible and how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all you need to do is just download your artifacts from JCenter.

On a related note, I'd suggest doing it the other way around - publish to JCenter and sync to Central. It should be easier for you.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: I have a artifact on maven central (latest version). I didn't publish the artifact into JCenter but I see it is there (not sure why). The issue is the jar on JCenter is not the latest version. How do I do? Thanks!

Comment: The latest jar will appear in the UI after first attempt to download it, but it's available there the second it was published in Maven Central. Just try to access it.

Comment: Thanks! I see it in JCenter now.

Comment: @JBaruch This doesn't seem to be true anymore? I've published com.needhamsoftware.unojar:ant:0.99.1 to central and it does not show at jcenter Does this answer need an update?